# QListWidget::clear() leads to Segmentation fault if a QListWidgetItem is selected

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget instance and when I select an QListWidgetItem with my mouse, if I later use QListWidget::clear(), I always get the same error.

So I looked up the Internet a bit and I added QListWidget::clearSelection() and QListWidget::clearFocus() before, but the result is the same. My code looks like:

`list.clearSelection();
list.clearFocus();
list.clear();`

And it works perfectly now!

Comment: Please format the code properly next time. Also, this is insufficient amount of information to help. Please provide more context, e.g. an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie here I somehow couldn't manage it. My file is 1800 lines long, so this is why I didn't provide code :/

Comment: Reduce your code to a simple test case that reproduces the problem. We cannot help without that. You did not even share the backtrace of the coredump, etc.

Comment: Okay I finally found out the cause of the segfault, but I still don't know why that is. I edited my OP accordingly. I'm sorry if my initial OP was so vague. I really couldn't understand what the matter was, but I was under the impression that it had nothing to do with my code somehow.

Comment: Great, so what was the issue?

Comment: The fact that I didn't use QListWidget::clearSelection() before QListWidget::clear() (QListWidget::Focus() is pointless in my problem) plus the fact that I didn't make sure an integer was positive somewhere else, but that problem could only be seen after I resolved the first one, described in the OP.